# How to fullScreen view of stackNavigator inside tabNavigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

this is my navigations :

```
-Navigations (Stack navigation)
   -Travel(Tab1)
      -OneWay(Tab2)
          -AirLineSearchResult(Stack navigation)
      -TwoWay(Tab2)
      -SeveralWay(Tab2)
   -Hotel (Tab1)
```

all of my navigation works correctly. but my AirLineSearchResult show inside tabs.I want some of my View show fullScreen. I try

> tabBarVisible:false

. and I change location of my page from AirLineSearchResult(stack navigation) to navigations (stack navigation) to become fullScreen, but its wrong work. how can I remove tabs and show Views fullScreen.

Answer (score 0):

In Tab-Navigator you can not show full screen view ,because tab navigator is root view that time, for that you can add a Modal For create a full screen view.

1. Create a class inside a tab navigator.
2. Add all children view inside of Modal view.

that would help you , It's help me.

Comment: inside my tab I have stack navigator and it's class. I don't understand Model View and didn't listen this name in react native. is there any article that help me?

Comment: Means Modal,You can refer this link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal

Comment: is there any way to exit from both tabs and open a new page without using modal to use another stack navigation process?

Comment: Yes you can do this,
Firstly create a stack inside stack, and  add tab stack and another stack(A) inside it. and when you want to exit from tab stack navigate to another stack(A) using this.



import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
  index: 0,
  params: {},

  // navigate can have a nested navigate action that will be run inside the child router
  action: NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'another stack (A)'}),
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should use the Show Inspector option of the [debug tool](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging) to figure out the reason why AirLineSearchResult didn't show fullscreen

Comment: I know why. because it is child of tab and show inside it. but I can't find a way to correct it.